# Создание меню для выбора с помощью стрелок на клавиатуре

Tags: python, pygame

Вот допустим у меня есть меню, и мне нужно сделать чтобы я с помощью стрелок на клавиатуре мог выбрать что я хочу.
Как такое провернуть? Хотелось бы использовать модуль PyGame.

```
What do you want
1) Sleep <<<
2) Play 
3) Eat
```

И после нажатия Enter происходило событие, которое я выбрал.

Буду очень благодарен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я уже нашёл решение.

Есть такой модуль SelectMenu 1.0.0b2

```
pip install SelectMenu
```

А вот его функционал:

```
>>> from selectmenu import SelectMenu
>>> menu = SelectMenu()
>>> menu.add_choices(
...    ["Python", "Ruby", "Javascript", "HTML", "CSS"])
>>> result = menu.select("What language do you like?")
What language do you like? (Use arrow keys)
 > Python
   Ruby
   Javascript
   HTML
   CSS
>>> print result
Python
```

P.s. И да, перед тем как его установить, нужно загрузить prompt toolkit

(У меня работает только на 1.0.14 версии, а у вас может и на 3.0.4 пойдёт)

```
pip install prompt_toolkit==1.0.14
```

Или

```
pip install prompt_toolkit
```

А вот и сама документация на английском - [SelectMenu • PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/SelectMenu/)